# Adobe AEM 6.1 Start up failed after Service Pack 2 upgrade

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr, sling

We require help.

We are applying Service Pack 2 to AEM 6.1 and SP2 deployment failed with Error 500. Unfortunately we've started the AEM and startup failed due to missing bundles or in correct bundle dependencies. We restored AEM from backup a which we took before night but while starting we received below error.

Any help to recover the instance is appreciated.

```
 * [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.TypeEditorProvider Node type change for cq:PollConfig requires repository scan: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plu
gins.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff[
        nodeTypeName=cq:PollConfig,
        mixinFlagDiff=NONE,
        supertypesDiff=NONE,
        propertyDifferences=[
                org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName=target, type=TRIVIAL, operation=MODIFIED],
                   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName=source, type=MAJOR, operation=ADDED]
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, whenever a node type definition is changed, OAK triggers a scan to ensure the consistency of the repository. AEM 6.1 SP2 upgrade has a few node type definition changes and depending on the size of your repository the full scan (which is basically an in-depth node traversal) could take a substantial amount of time (several hours).

The message you are seeing in the log is an INFO message and not an error. If you keep monitoring your logs, you will eventually see something like:

```
[FelixStartLevel] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.nodetype.TypeEditorProvider Node type changes: [cq:PollConfig, cq:PollConfig]; repository scan took <time duaration>ms
```

The startup is slow and hasn't failed unless you see errors from repository scans or other causes. Post an error if you see one and it can be looked at.

You can also try running the consistency checks via oak-run tool to verify the repository state after the upgrade. Detailed instructions can be found below:

https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/tree/trunk/oak-run

Note that this tool can work on offline repositories so you don't need a running instance to check for issues.

It is also recommended to install critical hotfixes and service packs using the crx-quickstart/install folder. Leave the packages in this folder after installation as they won't reinstall after subsequent startups but deleting some packages may uninstall them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the AEM got shut down after some time automatically No bundles were up and start up didn't get completed .
is this because of the SP2 patch improper deployment

Comment: Were there any errors or warnings in the logs or the system running low on memory CPU. Repository scan is pretty intensive. Is the TarMK or Mongo instance. Mongo scan is much slower in my experience.

Comment: SP2 on Primary author of AEM is failed , so we restore the AEM from before Night to do fresh installation and when we tried to start AEM it didn't start up and gave the above Info in error log , after some time we saw the below error in start up log and AEM got shut down automatically

Comment: 03.05.2017 17:02:59.984 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Error stopping launchpad:resources/install/0/com.adobe.granite.crxde-lite-1.0.88-CQ610-B0001.jar (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nothing re
gistered at /crx/de)

Comment: That error is normally raised wen the bundle is not installed properly or is corrupt. If your system console is up, then I would recommend to try installing this package via uploading the jar manually. You can extract the SP2 version of jar manually by unzipping it.

Comment: CRX is un availabe and packgmgr is not available to do it , so is there any other way to do it

Comment: You can use http://server:port/system/console/bundles and install/update button to upload bundles. This is the felix console so crx/de is not required

Comment: Can we install or uninstall /delete service patches also via server:port/system/console/bundles  ? for example i want to upload Adobe AEM 6.1 SP2 and install usually i do by upload and install via packgmgr .
is it possible to do the same by server:port/system/console/bundles

Comment: Service packs should normally be installed by placing them in crx-quickstart/install folder (create if it doesn't exist). Package manager is not the best way to install HF or SP as it requires active instance and some of these packages are best installed before bundles start. After shutting down the instance, place the zip file in crx-quickstart/install folder and the next startup will pick the package and install it. AFAIK, uninstallation cannot be done via console.

Comment: Thanks and That works ,Dond mind me for asking this after Placing SP2 in install folder and start the author it got installed well n good . and my query is now if i remove the package from install folder still SP2 will be installed for AEM or the package should be at install folder

Comment: Recommendation is to leave the packages in install folder. They won't be reinstalled but some packages can be uninstalled if removed from the install folder. Please mark as answer if this helped.